# SQL query returning 0 rows after adding extra INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

The issue is simple to explain, but seemingly not so simple to solve.

This SQL query returns 0 rows:

```
SELECT app_handover.*, sys_logins.first_name, sys_logins.last_name, sys_logins.dept_id, org_depts.dept_name
FROM ((app_handover
INNER JOIN sys_logins ON app_handover.sent_by = sys_logins.id)
INNER JOIN org_depts ON sys_logins.dept_id = org_depts.id)
WHERE app_handover.id = '12'
```

This one, however, returns 1 row as I expected:

```
SELECT app_handover.*, sys_logins.first_name, sys_logins.last_name, sys_logins.dept_id
FROM app_handover
INNER JOIN sys_logins ON app_handover.sent_by = sys_logins.id
WHERE app_handover.id = '12'
```

The only difference is the lack of `INNER JOIN` with the `org_depts` table.

What I want to be returned is all the column values from `app_handover`, which references `sys_logins.id` in its `sent_by` column. I also want the value of `org_depts.dept_name`, which is referenced by `sys_logins.dept_id`.

I cannot think of an alternative syntax to use, but clearly there is an error in my logic in the first example, which is returning 0 rows instead of 1 as I expected.

Comment: I guess you want a LEFT JOIN. (Since there's no matching org_depts row.)

Comment: Try by changing INNER to LEFT join in first one. Seemingly for the record you are getting, there is not a valid dept_id.

Comment: check org_depts to see if the ids you expect are in there. Maybe its a different id? Or maybe org_depts is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, LEFT JOIN was the answer. The value of `dept_id` in the matching `sys_logins` row was `NULL`, so no matching record was found in `org_depts`.

This query works and now returns 1 row:

```
SELECT app_handover.*, sys_logins.first_name, sys_logins.last_name, sys_logins.dept_id, org_depts.dept_name
FROM ((app_handover
INNER JOIN sys_logins ON app_handover.sent_by = sys_logins.id)
LEFT JOIN org_depts ON sys_logins.dept_id = org_depts.id)
WHERE app_handover.id = '12'
```